# Java 7 update 11 breaks webb app on IE8 with Apache Tomcat 6.0.36

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, internet-explorer-8

I run web apps on Apache Tomcat 6.0.36 and use IE8 for a web browser with Windows 7 .  I have recently applied the Java zero day patch (Java 7 Update 11).

Now all of my web applications get a  white screen with the message 'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage' Here is the error message I get from my catalina log file.

```
Jan 18, 2013 3:44:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 38198 ms
Jan 18, 2013 3:51:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint setSocketOptions
SEVERE:
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: no further information
at sun.nio.ch.Net.setIntOption0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.setSocketOption(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.setOption(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.setIntOption(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.setTrafficClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProperties.setProperties(SocketProperties.java:184)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.setSocketOptions(NioEndpoint.java:1089)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1314)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: How does this relate to IE8?

Answer (score 3):

Reason is setTrafficClass call and have bit the same bullet once. If you used Java6 to run Tomcat process it should work. Something to do with Windows network stack features. Some apps provide an attribute "skipTrafficClass_call=true" but thats a part of the application behaviour. This is very old issue but Java7 made a small but significant change.

Quote from internet:

> "I've tracked down the first of these issues. Calling
> java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.socket().setTrafficClass() after
> socketChannel.connect() has been called triggers a SocketException.
> Moving the setTrafficClass() call to before connect() fixes the
> issue." " Tests on Java 6 show that the setTrafficClass() was having
> no effect if called after connect(). It looks like Java 7 has started
> to throw an exception when the setter has no effect."
>
> A number of developers on the JDC have posted comments to indicate
> that the ToS bits are not set on Windows 2000 and XP. This is not a
> bug in the setTrafficClass implementation but rather that the IP_TOS
> option must be enabled by creating a registry setting. The registry
> setting is :-
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\DisableUserTOSSetting

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTrafficClass%28int%29

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4696356

http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/Tomcat-7-Cluster-Issue-td4562937.html

You could try older Http11Protocol handler for connectors, this is given in tomcat/conf/server.xml file. Change both http(8080) and https(8443) connectors.

```
<!-- protocol: org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol, same as HTTP/1.1
           org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol
           org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
       connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" 
       disableUploadTimeout="true" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />
```

**edit** It seems Tomcat 7.0.30+ fixed the issue and you may use Windows+Java7+Tomcat7+NIO connector. From now on all java network apps should set optional socket options before opening a connection, Java6 gave a free pass but Java7 throws an exception.
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1358591